# PrestaShop debug error 500

Tags: prestashop, http-status-code-500

I'm developing a module for PrestaShop but I'm getting a 500 error page.

I've check Apache logs and PrestaShop logs but I can't seem to find the problem behind this error.

How can I enable debugging mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to PrestaShop documentation you can do the following:

**For PrestaShop v1.4 through v1.5.2**

Open config/config.inc.php

On or around line 29 you will find this line

```
@ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
```

Change that line to read

```
@ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

**For PrestaShop v1.5.3+**

Open config/defines.inc.php

On or around line 28 you will find this

```
line define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);
```

Change that line to read

```
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
```

You can read further on this subject [here](https://www.prestashop.com/blog/en/the-500-internal-server-error-explained-solved/).